# Make AVI file from H264 compressed data

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, avi

I'm using ffmpeg libraries to create a AVI file and following the `muxing.c ffmpeg` example as below

1. Allocate the output media context:  `avformat_alloc_output_context2`
2. Add video streams using the `AV_CODEC_ID_H264` codec with below set of parameters:

   ```
   int AddVideoStream(AVStream *&video_st, AVFormatContext *&oc, AVCodec **codec, enum AVCodecID codec_id){

   AVCodecContext *c;

   /* find the encoder */
   *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id); //codec id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264
   if (!(*codec)) {
       sprintf(strError , "Could not find encoder for '%s' line %d\n", avcodec_get_name(codec_id), __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }

   video_st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
   if (!video_st) {
       sprintf(strError , "Could not allocate stream line %d\n", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }
   video_st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
   c = video_st->codec;

   avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, *codec);
   c->codec_id = codec_id;

   c->bit_rate = 500*1000;
   /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
   c->width    = 1280;
   c->height   = 720;
   /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
   * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
   * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
   * identical to 1. */
   c->time_base.den = 25*1000;
   c->time_base.num = 1000;
   c->gop_size      = 12;//(int)(av_q2d(c->time_base) / 2);    // GOP size is framerate/2 
   c->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
   /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
   if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
       c->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

   return RS_OK;
   ```

   }
3. Open Video stream: `open_video`

   `int open_video( AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, AVStream *st ){`

   ```
   int ret;
   AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;
   char strError[STR_LENGTH_256];
   /* open the codec */
   ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
   if (ret < 0) {
       sprintf(strError , "Could not open video codec line %d", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }

   /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
   frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
   if (!frame) {
       sprintf(strError , "Could not allocate video frame line %d", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }

   /* Allocate the encoded raw picture. */
   ret = avpicture_alloc(&dst_picture, c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
   if (ret < 0) {
       sprintf(strError , "Could not allocate picture line %d", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }

   /* If the output format is not YUV420P, then a temporary YUV420P
   * picture is needed too. It is then converted to the required
   * output format. */
   if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
       ret = avpicture_alloc(&src_picture, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);
       if (ret < 0) {
           sprintf(strError , "Could not allocate temporary picture line %d", __LINE__);
           commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
           return RS_NOT_OK;
       }
   }

   /* copy data and linesize picture pointers to frame */
   *((AVPicture *)frame) = dst_picture;
   return RS_OK;
   ```

   }
4. Write AVI stream header: `avformat_write_header`
5. Encode video frame:`avcodec_encode_video2`

   Case a: The input here are `BRG frames` so I encode them to H264 and pass to the next step.

   Case b: The input here are `H264 compressed frames (these frames captured from H264 RTP stream)` so I leave this step then move to next step.
6. Write Interleave Video frame: `av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt)`

   Case a:  Writing the packet data encoded from step 5 correctly without error.

   Case b:  I Always get error from `av_interleaved_write_frame` with value -22. It could be EINVAL invalid argument. So someone can tell me what is wrong? or Some parameters I was missing here.

   ```
   int WriteVideoFrame(AVFormatContext *&oc, AVStream *&st, 
   uint8_t *imageData `/*BRG data input*/`, 
   int width, 
   int height, 
   bool isStart, 
   bool isData,
   bool isCompressed, 
   AVPacket* packet `/*H264 data input*/`)
   ```

   {

   `if (isCompressed == false)// For BRG data`
   {

   ```
   static struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
   AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;

   if (isData)
   {
       if (!frame) {
           //fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
           return RS_NOT_OK;
       }
       if (isStart == true)
           frame->pts = 0;
       /* Allocate the encoded raw picture. */
       if (width != c->width || height != c->height)
       {
           if (!sws_ctx)
           {
               sws_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height,
                   AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, c->width, c->height,
                   AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, 0, 0, 0);

               if (!sws_ctx)
               {
                   sprintf(strError, "Could not initialize the conversion context line %d\n", __LINE__);
                   commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
                   return RS_NOT_OK;
               }
           }
           uint8_t * inData[1] = { imageData }; // RGB24 have one plane
           int inLinesize[1] = { 3 * width }; // RGB stride
           sws_scale(sws_ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, height, dst_picture.data, dst_picture.linesize);
       }
       else
           BRG24ToYUV420p(dst_picture.data, imageData, width, height); //Phong Le changed this
   }
   if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE)
   {
       /* Raw video case - directly store the picture in the packet */
       AVPacket pkt;
       av_init_packet(&pkt);

       pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
       pkt.stream_index = st->index;
       pkt.data = dst_picture.data[0];
       pkt.size = sizeof(AVPicture);

       ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
       av_free_packet(&pkt);
   }
   else
   {
       /* encode the image */
       AVPacket pkt;
       int got_output;

       av_init_packet(&pkt);
       pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
       pkt.size = 0;
       ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
       if (ret < 0) {
           sprintf(strError, "Error encoding video frame line %d\n", __LINE__);
           commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
           av_free_packet(&pkt);
           return RS_NOT_OK;
       }

       /* If size is zero, it means the image was buffered. */
       if (got_output) {
           if (c->coded_frame->key_frame)
               pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

           pkt.stream_index = st->index;

           /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
           ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
       }
       else
       {
           ret = 0;
       }
       av_free_packet(&pkt);
   }
   if (ret != 0)
   {
       sprintf(strError, "Error while writing video frame line %d\n", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }
   frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, st->codec->time_base, st->time_base);
   return RS_OK;
   ```

   }

   else /*H264 data*/

   {

   ```
   if (isStart == true)
       packet->pts = 0;

   else
       packet->pts += av_rescale_q(1, st->codec->time_base, st->time_base);

   ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, packet);
   if (ret < 0)
   {
       sprintf(strError, "Error while writing video frame line %d\n", __LINE__);
       commonGlobal->WriteRuntimeBackupLogs(strError);
       return RS_NOT_OK;
   }

   return RS_OK;
   ```

   }

}

7. Close file.

->   Case a: Creating AVI file successful.

->   Case b: Fail.

Thanks
Tien Vo

Comment: Without seeing some code, any answers will just be guesses.

Comment: I've just added piece of code of step 5-6. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: By setting pts and dts with AV_NOPTS_VALUE I've solved the problem.